# Right number of letters are not appearing in python tkinter game

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a jumbled word but the right amount of letters are not showing when running the code. There's only 1 letter being displayed and if the user actually inputs the right answer, the code only takes it as a wrong answer. Is there a way to fix this problem? Thank you!

```
    import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import shuffle



answer =["python", "youtube","google","samosa","india","tea","coffee"]
words= []

for i in answer:
    words= list(i)
    shuffle(words)
    words.append(words)

num= random.randint(0,len(words))


def initial():
    global words,answer,num
    lbl1.configure(text=words[num])



def ans_check():
    print(" ")
    global words,num,answer
    user_input= e1.get()
    if user_input==answer[num]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Success","yup, this is right!")
        Reset()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error","Make sure it's without capitals")
        e1.delete(0,END)


def Reset():
    global words,num,answer
    num= random.randint(0,len(words))
    lbl1.configure(text=words[num])
    e1.delete(0,END)


root= Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

lbl1= Label(root,font='times 20')
lbl1.pack(pady=30,ipady=10,ipadx=10)

answer12= StringVar()
e1= Entry(root,textvariable=answer)
e1.pack(ipady=5,ipadx=5)

bt1= Button(root,text='Check',width=20,command=ans_check)
bt1.pack(pady=40)

bt2= Button(root,text='Reset',width=20,command=Reset)
bt2.pack()
initial()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O lord how many problems this has :). Dont worry!
First of all, your biggest problem is you created a list called `words` to contain a list of shuffled words. Then you create the same variable called `words` which stores `list(word)`. This messes up your program entirely.

Also, if your user is incorrect, tell them they got it wrong. Dont show an error for capitalization. To avoid this, you can use `.lower()`

**Code**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import shuffle



answer =["python", "youtube","google","samosa","india","tea","coffee"]
words_lst= []

for i in answer:
    word = list(i)
    shuffle(word)
    words_lst.append(word)


num= random.randint(0,len(words_lst))

def initial():
    global words,answer,num
    lbl1.configure(text=answer[num])



def ans_check():
    print(" ")
    global words,num,answer
    user_input= e1.get()
    if user_input.lower()==answer[num]:
        messagebox.showinfo("Success","yup, this is right!")
        Reset()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error","Incorrect")
        e1.delete(0,END)


def Reset():
    global words,num,answer
    num= random.randint(0,len(words_lst))
    lbl1.configure(text=words_lst[num])
    e1.delete(0,END)


root= Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

lbl1= Label(root,font='times 20')
lbl1.pack(pady=30,ipady=10,ipadx=10)

answer12= StringVar()
e1= Entry(root,textvariable=answer)
e1.pack(ipady=5,ipadx=5)

bt1= Button(root,text='Check',width=20,command=ans_check)
bt1.pack(pady=40)

bt2= Button(root,text='Reset',width=20,command=Reset)
bt2.pack()
initial()
root.mainloop()
```